# IPSec tunnel causes huge packets lost when pinging gateway and other machines

Tags: networking, linux-networking, ipsec, ubuntu-18.04, icmp

My Ubuntu machine is 10.0.0.15, my Windows machine is 10.0.0.10. My gateway, that routes the Internet traffic to the LAN is 10.0.0.1.

When I ping the gateway from my Windows machine everything is fine - I get every single packet back. Same holds true, when I ping the Ubuntu machine from the Windows machine. However, when I ping the gateway from Ubuntu machine around 80% of packets are lost:

```
~# ping 10.0.0.1
PING 10.0.0.1 (10.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=16 ttl=64 time=0.460 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=29 ttl=64 time=0.464 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=30 ttl=64 time=0.477 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=77 ttl=64 time=0.498 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=91 ttl=64 time=0.452 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=92 ttl=64 time=0.690 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=94 ttl=64 time=0.539 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=95 ttl=64 time=0.445 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=96 ttl=64 time=0.541 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=98 ttl=64 time=0.474 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=99 ttl=64 time=1.40 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=103 ttl=64 time=0.577 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=106 ttl=64 time=0.535 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=107 ttl=64 time=0.490 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=109 ttl=64 time=0.477 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=110 ttl=64 time=0.627 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=111 ttl=64 time=0.563 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=114 ttl=64 time=0.467 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=115 ttl=64 time=0.535 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=137 ttl=64 time=0.479 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=138 ttl=64 time=0.455 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=142 ttl=64 time=0.548 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=143 ttl=64 time=0.448 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=144 ttl=64 time=0.470 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=147 ttl=64 time=0.545 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=149 ttl=64 time=0.557 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=152 ttl=64 time=0.547 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=153 ttl=64 time=0.476 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=179 ttl=64 time=0.472 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=180 ttl=64 time=0.854 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=188 ttl=64 time=0.494 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=190 ttl=64 time=0.556 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=192 ttl=64 time=0.499 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=193 ttl=64 time=0.482 ms
^C
--- 10.0.0.1 ping statistics ---
194 packets transmitted, 34 received, 82% packet loss, time 197372ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.445/0.546/1.404/0.171 ms
```

Same thing happens when I ping any IP address on the Internet (== through the gateway). However, if I ping any other machine on the LAN, then everything is fine (for example the Windows machine).

This has not always been the case. I lately configured an IPSec tunnel, so it may be the cause. However, even with the IPSec tunnel stopped I experience the same issues.

I checked the routing and it does not behave as I would expect it.

Traceroute to another machine in the LAN looks fine:

```
~# traceroute 10.0.0.7
traceroute to 10.0.0.7 (10.0.0.7), 64 hops max
  1   10.0.0.7  0.173ms  0.115ms  0.180ms
```

Traceroute to the gateway does *not* look fine (had to `CTRL+C` - it was stuck for too long):

```
~# traceroute 10.0.0.1
traceroute to 10.0.0.1 (10.0.0.1), 64 hops max
^C
```

Routing table looks good:

```
~# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.0.0.1        0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp5s0
10.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 enp5s0
10.0.0.1        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    100    0        0 enp5s0
```

**EDIT:**
I already know the issue is caused by the tunnel. When I disable the service (`sudo systemctl disable strongswan`) and reboot the computer pinging works properly. If I then manually start the tunnel (`ipsec start`) pinging does not work (works in a way described above). If I then stop the tunnel (`ipsec stop`) it still won't change anything. I need to reboot the computer to fix it.

My IPSec config is:

```
# ipsec.conf - strongSwan IPsec configuration file

config setup
        # strictcrlpolicy=yes
        # uniqueids = no

conn my-tunnel
        type=tunnel
        keyexchange=ikev1
        authby=secret
        left=%defaultroute
        leftid=Y.Y.Y.Y
        leftsubnet=10.0.0.0/24
        right=X.X.X.X
        rightsubnet=192.168.0.0/24
        ike=aes256-sha1-modp2048!
        esp=aes256-sha1-modp2048!
        keyingtries=0
        ikelifetime=1h
        lifetime=8h
        dpddelay=30
        dpdtimeout=120
        dpdaction=restart
        auto=start
```

Do you have any suggestions where I could have a look and possibly fix the issue?

**EDIT2:** (as requested by Kevin K. in the comments)

Keep in mind that X.X.X.X is a remote public IP address, that I replaced myself.

```
~# ip xfrm state
src 10.0.0.15 dst X.X.X.X
        proto esp spi 0xc44dd838 reqid 1 mode tunnel
        replay-window 0 flag af-unspec
        mark 0x64/0xffffffff
        auth-trunc hmac(sha1) 0x951ac2ff6fadcd180b86e91ddf850c96f9e09ec2 96
        enc cbc(aes) 0x0b17feeeafb55e1693c1e1c3f8d59b3a1d2c5470e4fc7580b0887e0a8beb504d
        encap type espinudp sport 4500 dport 4500 addr 0.0.0.0
        anti-replay context: seq 0x0, oseq 0x0, bitmap 0x00000000
src X.X.X.X dst 10.0.0.15
        proto esp spi 0xc364db19 reqid 1 mode tunnel
        replay-window 32 flag af-unspec
        auth-trunc hmac(sha1) 0x00b17673c57fac4957123718d046578689edb07a 96
        enc cbc(aes) 0xedd573110a33a7ac100372fa605514703b0f9954b33a3780dd97ee8e8ac32fe5
        encap type espinudp sport 4500 dport 4500 addr 0.0.0.0
        anti-replay context: seq 0x0, oseq 0x0, bitmap 0x00000000
```

```
~# ip xfrm policy
src 10.0.0.0/24 dst 192.168.0.0/24
        dir out priority 376959
        mark 0x64/0xffffffff
        tmpl src 10.0.0.15 dst X.X.X.X
                proto esp spi 0xc44dd838 reqid 1 mode tunnel
src 192.168.0.0/21 dst 10.0.0.0/24
        dir fwd priority 376959
        mark 0x64/0xffffffff
        tmpl src X.X.X.X dst 10.0.0.15
                proto esp reqid 1 mode tunnel
src 192.168.0.0/21 dst 10.0.0.0/24
        dir in priority 376959
        mark 0x64/0xffffffff
        tmpl src X.X.X.X dst 10.0.0.15
                proto esp reqid 1 mode tunnel
src 0.0.0.0/0 dst 0.0.0.0/0
        socket in priority 0
src 0.0.0.0/0 dst 0.0.0.0/0
        socket out priority 0
src 0.0.0.0/0 dst 0.0.0.0/0
        socket in priority 0
src 0.0.0.0/0 dst 0.0.0.0/0
        socket out priority 0
src ::/0 dst ::/0
        socket in priority 0
src ::/0 dst ::/0
        socket out priority 0
src ::/0 dst ::/0
        socket in priority 0
src ::/0 dst ::/0
        socket out priority 0
```

I decided to let ping go for some time. It looks like I receive response for a second or so and then it stops again. In the below example I am sending 10 packets per second (`-i 0.1`). You can distinguish the consecutive packets by looking at icmp_seq parameter.

```
root@phenom:~# ping 10.0.0.1 -i 0.1
PING 10.0.0.1 (10.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=656 ttl=64 time=0.572 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=657 ttl=64 time=0.501 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=658 ttl=64 time=0.518 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=659 ttl=64 time=0.464 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=660 ttl=64 time=0.491 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=661 ttl=64 time=0.561 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=662 ttl=64 time=0.571 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=663 ttl=64 time=0.545 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=664 ttl=64 time=0.584 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=665 ttl=64 time=0.549 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=666 ttl=64 time=0.564 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=667 ttl=64 time=0.539 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=668 ttl=64 time=0.587 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=669 ttl=64 time=0.531 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=670 ttl=64 time=0.832 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=671 ttl=64 time=0.903 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=747 ttl=64 time=0.511 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=748 ttl=64 time=0.483 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=749 ttl=64 time=0.472 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=914 ttl=64 time=0.553 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=915 ttl=64 time=0.568 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=916 ttl=64 time=0.553 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=917 ttl=64 time=0.589 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=918 ttl=64 time=0.556 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=919 ttl=64 time=0.573 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=920 ttl=64 time=0.574 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=921 ttl=64 time=0.556 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=922 ttl=64 time=0.551 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=923 ttl=64 time=0.607 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=934 ttl=64 time=0.848 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=935 ttl=64 time=0.555 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=936 ttl=64 time=1.00 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=937 ttl=64 time=0.586 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=938 ttl=64 time=0.566 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=939 ttl=64 time=0.495 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=940 ttl=64 time=0.551 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=941 ttl=64 time=0.456 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=953 ttl=64 time=0.453 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=954 ttl=64 time=0.478 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=955 ttl=64 time=0.567 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=956 ttl=64 time=0.585 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=957 ttl=64 time=0.488 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=958 ttl=64 time=0.586 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=959 ttl=64 time=0.486 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=960 ttl=64 time=0.543 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=961 ttl=64 time=0.442 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=962 ttl=64 time=0.443 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=963 ttl=64 time=0.528 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=964 ttl=64 time=0.475 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=965 ttl=64 time=0.474 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=966 ttl=64 time=0.839 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=967 ttl=64 time=0.461 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=968 ttl=64 time=0.474 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=969 ttl=64 time=0.474 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=970 ttl=64 time=0.547 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=971 ttl=64 time=0.837 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=972 ttl=64 time=18.6 ms
^C
--- 10.0.0.1 ping statistics ---
1174 packets transmitted, 57 received, 95% packet loss, time 121969ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.442/0.883/18.628/2.374 ms
```

Comment: From [Strongswan.org](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/IntroductionTostrongSwan#Logging-and-Monitoring): _On Linux, the iproute2 package provides the `ip xfrm state` and `ip xfrm policy` commands to request detailed information about the IPsec SAs and policies installed in the kernel._ Could you append the output of these two commands when the connection is not working as expected, please?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I added the output of both commands.

Comment: Why do you have a host route for 10.0.0.1? That's not normal. Note that the `route` command is deprecated, use iproute's `ip route` instead.

Comment: @wurtel what are you referring to? Do you mean `10.0.0.1 dev enp5s0 proto dhcp scope link src 10.0.0.15 metric 100`? This is the gateway to the Internet. I have the exact same line on another Ubuntu machine in the network.

Comment: That gateway is accessible via the network route for 10.0.0.0/24 so there's no reason to add a host routing entry. I don't have those on any of my Debian or Red Hat systems. even those with an IPsec tunnel.

Comment: OK. I removed it with `ip route del 10.0.0.1` and `ip route show` shows only the remaining two lines. I still cannot ping 10.0.0.1 though. Keep in mind that other protocols work. E.g. `curl http://10.0.0.1` returns html returned by 10.0.0.1.

Also it's not like ICMP does not work at all. Sometimes it works. But if I am lucky, I will get around 20% ICMP responses. The rest is lost.

Comment: I will only add that pings work flawlessly for around 2 minutes after the reboot. After that time ping stops working for the most part. `syslog` does not show anything interesting taking place around that time. The IPSec tunnel is up from the very beginning so it's not related to the tunnel connection being established.